# how to display textview items from edittext in listview one by one in another layout?

Tags: android

I am trying to show textview items from entries in edittext on button click to listview in another layout with scrollview.. Code is not running.. application error so help me.

this is my xml..

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context=".MainActivity" >

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button3"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/spinner1"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/editText5"
    android:text="@string/add" />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/editText5"
    android:layout_width="80dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/textView5"
    android:layout_alignTop="@+id/textView5"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    android:ems="10"
    android:inputType="number" />

<RelativeLayout
android:layout_width="70dp"
android:layout_height="140dp"
android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
android:layout_alignTop="@+id/spinner1"
android:layout_marginTop="17dp" >

 <ScrollView 
     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:scrollbars="vertical">    
 </ScrollView>
 <ListView 
     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
     android:layout_height="125dp">
 </ListView>
```

this is my java code.

```
private Button mbtn_currencyadd;    
private EditText medit_currency;
private TextView mtv1=null;
private ListView mlv;
public String s1;

protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    mtv1=new TextView(this);
    mlv.addView(mtv1);
    //mll2.addView(mtv2);
    mbtn_currencyadd=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button3);
    medit_currency=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText5);

    mbtn_currencyadd.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
               s1=medit_currency.getText().toString();
               s1=mtv1.getText().toString()+"\n"+s1;
               mtv1.setText(s1);
               mtv1.setTextSize(17);
               medit_currency.setText(""); 

        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at [this](http://ravikanthandroid.blogspot.in/2013/07/dynamically-adding-items-to-list-view.html) example.

It is very similar to what you are looking for.Items are added dynamically from Edit text to list view on button click

You can ask if you have any further queries :)

Answer (score 0):

Of course it won't work. Here's why: -

1. You list view doesn't have an id
2. You are not getting a reference to your listview (m1v) in your activity
3. In order to add items to a listview, you need to create an adapter

See this example http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/listview.html